# Editing in Chrome behaves differently than in Firefox or Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, editing

Consider this bit of HTML when rendered in a web browser:

```
<p contenteditable="true"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Bold</span>.</p>
```

In Firefox 66 and Edge 17, highlighting all five characters of text (i.e., including the full stop) and typing the word "New", for example, results in the following markup:

```
<p contenteditable="true"><span style="font-weight:bold;">New</span></p>
```

However, if you do the same thing in Chrome 73, you get:

```
<p contenteditable="true"><b>New</b></p>
```

Chrome seems to have decided to replace the span with a *b* element to achieve the same visual effect.

Is there any way to stop this happening? I have a text editor that is getting very confused by this behaviour.

You can play with this

```html
<p contenteditable="true"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Bold</span>.</p>
```

Note: If all the text is within the span (so no full stop in this example), the *b* element is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right ***Chrome*** decide to replace the new text with a similar styling

so what you need to block chrome from doing that is [Document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)
and it will keep the previous element before deletion with previous styling.

so the command you need is `styleWithCSS` which replace what inside `contentEditable` with style.

> **styleWithCSS**
>
> Replaces the useCSS command. true modifies/generates style attributes in markup, false generates presentational elements.

```
document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, 'true')
```

```js
document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, 'true')
```

```html
    <p contenteditable="true">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Bold</span>.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes Chrome behave like Firefox and Edge.